# Unity - why I cannot play through script the sounds I need?

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine

I have the AudioSources as childrens of my player object where I got the script that I am using.

So I implement the Audiosources in the main class:

```
public AudioSource good_morning;
public AudioSource stroke_message;
public AudioSource citysound;
public AudioSource silence;
```

and then in void Start() I am trying to get components and play 1 of them. but nothing is happening.. can you help me with this?

```
citysound = GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource>();
good_morning = GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource> ();
stroke_message = GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource> ();
silence = GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource>();
good_morning.Play ();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suspect is you don't have an audio clip assigned to your `AudioSource` in the scene.

What I'm sure of is you don't fully understand how to use `GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource>();`. It iterates through children of your transform; after detecting an `AudioSource` in one of them it just stops and returns it. So basically, all of your variables would be set to the same `AudioSource`. I'd advise you to remove the first 4 lines from your second code snippet and assign the `AudioSources` from Unity editor manually so that you would be sure each one is assigned to correct variable.

Comment: Especially since the audio sources are declared as public variables.

Comment: thank you! I don't need to use the GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource>

Answer (score 0):

try this in

```
void start()
{
AudioSource citysound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
AudioSource good_morning = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
AudioSource stroke_message = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
AudioSource silence = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
good_morning.Play ();
}
```

Comment: no I needed to delete this:
AudioSource citysound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
AudioSource good_morning = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
AudioSource stroke_message = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
AudioSource silence = GetComponent<AudioSource>();